# Apache Pig - Null check in case statement

Tags: apache-pig

How do I test for null in a case statement?

```
case foo    
      when null then 'something'
      when 'S' then '1'
      when 'W' then '2'
      ...
      else '3'
end
```

This always returns null, regardless of what's in the field.  `When is null` returns an error.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to put together some awful nested bincond test?

Comment: Why the downvote, do I need to add information?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted.It's definitely a valid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can check for null in case statement.Instead, you can use bincond operator to first check for null value and then use the case statement for the rest of 'foo' values

Assuming A has just one field with null values in few rows

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (foo is null ? 'something' : (case foo    
      when 'S' then '1'
      when 'W' then '2'
      ...
      else '3'
end));
```

**Example**

```
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
```

**Script** - Generate some nulls for testing and replace with 'SOMETHING'

```
A = LOAD '/test20.txt' AS (f1:int,f2:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE $1;
D = JOIN B BY $0 LEFT OUTER,C BY $0;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE $0, ($1 is null ? 'SOMETHING' : (case $1 
                  when 1 then 'One'
                  when 2 then 'Two'
                  when 3 then 'Three'
                  when 4 then 'Four'
                  else 'UNKNOWN'
                  end));

 DUMP E;
```

**Output**

[image]